# Translating nested asynchronous functions to node.js Async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

So I'm working on a movie website to practice my node.js/angular skills. Recently I noticed that I have a lot of nested asynchronous functions on my server side. Many people suggested using the async.js module for this.

Below there are two different versions of the same server side objective. One is the original nested async functions and the other one is what I came up with using Async.js. Could someone see if I did it the right way, used the right method in this case (waterfall) and perhaps give me some corrections that could improve my code? It works, but maybe you guys can see some improvements? For example: Is there an alternative to passing the variables to the arguments every time ( like I did with reviewId e.g)

- Extra question:

  What are the most used methods of the async.js module? Cause there are like hundreds and I would just like to learn the most important ones.

**This is what I came up with when I tried to translate the nested asynchronous functions below**

```
router.delete('/deleteReview/:reviewId', function(req, res, next) {
    async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            var reviewId = req.params.reviewId;
            Review.find({'_id': reviewId})
                .populate('user')
                .populate('movie')
                .exec(function(err, review){
                    callback(null, review, reviewId)
                });
        },
        function (review, reviewId, callback) {
            var index = review[0].user.reviews.indexOf(reviewId);
            review[0].user.reviews.splice(index, 1);
            review[0].user.save(function(err, user){
              callback(null, user, reviewId, review)
            })
        },
        function (user, reviewId, review, callback) {
            var index = review[0].movie.reviews.indexOf(reviewId);
            review[0].movie.reviews.splice(index, 1);
            review[0].movie.save(function(err, movie){
                callback(null, movie, index)
            });
        }
    ], function (err, result, index) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: "An error occurred",
                obj: err
            })
        }
        res.status(200).json({
            message: "successful",
            obj: index
        })
    });
});
```

**the original nested asynchronous functions**

```
router.delete('/deleteReview/:reviewId', function(req, res, next){
   var reviewId = req.params.reviewId;
    Review.find({'_id': reviewId})
        .populate('user')
        .populate('movie')
        .exec(function(err, review){
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    message: "An error occurred",
                    obj: err
                })
            }
            var index = review[0].user.reviews.indexOf(reviewId);
            review[0].user.reviews.splice(index, 1);
            review[0].user.save(function(err, user){
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).json({
                        message: "An error occurred",
                        obj: err
                    })
                }
                var index = review[0].movie.reviews.indexOf(reviewId);
                review[0].movie.reviews.splice(index, 1);
                review[0].movie.save(function(err, movie){
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(500).json({
                            message: "An error occurred",
                            obj: err
                        })
                    }
                    res.status(200).json({
                        message: "successful",
                        obj: index
                    })
                })

            });
        })
});
```

Comment: async.js is a great library, but now when ES has built-in Promises and async/await, it feels a little bit obsolete.

Comment: Is it still handy for methods like async.parallel? Or are the new build-in promises also able to handle that?

Comment: yep, in most cases `async.map` === `Promise.all` and `async.some` === `Promise.race`.

Comment: Haha ok, guess I'll check that out now.